# How to make a transition to the specific slide, JQuery cicle plugn

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, cycle

How to make a transition to the specific slide, for example if i have 1,2,3,4,5 buttons, the current slide is 4, and i want go to the 2 slide, how can i do it in cycle plugin of JQuery

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults = {
    animIn:        {},
    animOut:       {},
    fx:           'fade',
    after:         null, 
    before:        null, 
    cssBefore:     {},
    cssAfter:      {},
    delay:         0,    
    fit:           0,    
    height:       'auto',
    metaAttr:     'cycle',
    next:          null, 
    pause:         0,    
    prev:          null, 
    speed:         1000, 
    slideExpr:     null,
    sync:          1,    
    timeout:       4000 
};
```

which of these options can be used to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html) and [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager.html), it is evident that the cycle plugin supports paging out of the box by use of the `pager` option, which specifies what element should act as the pager.

```
$('#s4') 
.before('<div id="nav">') //insert the pager element before the cycled element
.cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    pager:  '#nav' 
});
```